# Can't login to admin with no errors (joomla 3.9.3)

Tags: joomla-3.x, login, administration, authentication

My site on Joomla 3.9.3 is working well but since last week no one admin user can log in. There are no errors, the login form just refreshes after any submission.
I've tried to rewrite Joomla core files, to edit passwords in DB and to disable/enable some plugins referring to authentication in _extensions table, but all my tries did not affect.
Any suggestions?

Comment: We don't have a lot to go on here.  You may need to print to screen some checkpoints to narrow down where the failure is occurring.  What precisely did you (or someone) do last week just before the problem began? Did you turn off all extensions and try to login in?  We need more, please continue to explore and run diagnostics.  Edit your question if you make any new discoveries.  Please also take the [tour] while you wait.

Comment: When you normally access your Admin area do have an extension installed where it requires you to add an extra value to the URL. For example  hhttp:/yoursite/administrator?something ?

Comment: Try to rename the .htaccess file in the root folder to see whether it's something related to .htaccess

Comment: Please update to Joomla 3.9.11 and try again. You should always be on the latest version